# NextJS Import error that only occurs in the /api/ route

Tags: typescript, next.js, importerror

I have an import error using NextJS that only occurs in the `/pages/api/` route.

#### `store.d.ts`:

In my `/util/storeUtil.ts` file, I import 3 things from `/util/store.d.ts` like this:

```js
import {REQUEST_OPTIONS, type productDataMap, type storeDataMap } from './store';
```

This works fine while coding and running this file individually, but the issue arises when I import it into my `/pages/api/store_results.ts` file like this:

#### `/pages/api/store_results.ts`:

```js
import someFunction from '../../utils/storeUtils';
```

#### This is the error:

I get this error when I go to `http://localhost:3000/api/store_results`

```
./utils/storeUtils.ts:1:0
Module not found: Can't resolve './store'
> 1 | import {REQUEST_OPTIONS, type productDataMap, type storeDataMap } from './store';
  2 | 
  3 | 
  4 | 

Import trace for requested module:
./pages/api/store_results.ts

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

### The issue:

This is the part of the code in `store.d.ts` that is causing issues:

```js
interface options {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'API-Key': string,
        'API-Host': string
    }
}

export declare const REQUEST_OPTIONS: options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'API-Key': process.env.API_KEY,
        'API-Host': process.env.API_HOST
    }
};
```

#### Attempted fix:

When I remove the import for `REQUEST_OPTIONS` in `/util/storeUtil.ts`, the error does not occur. I am not sure why this error is happening, and I could use some help.

I am pretty new to TypeScript and NextJS so apologies if this is a simple problem.